# Can we edit the "edit summary" of a post?

Tags: discussion

One of our [popular questions](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6828/31284) was edited recently. I initially rejected the edit. I don't disagree with adding metric units into the questions, rather, the anonymous editor left a bit of a rude "edit summary", IMO, and I didn't want it saved there.

Can we axe the edit summary somehow and leave the metric units? What's the best way to approach that in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited the message, and thanks for pointing it out!

Next time this occurs, I expect you to have the privileges to [do it yourself](https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/854/2021-moderator-election-qa-question-collection), hint hint.

Comment: Lmaoo, hint received. I'll think on it. Thanks for editing.